# Ball falls through platform collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

There are 2 GameObjects; a platform and a ball.

The ball is controlled via a custom controller, and the platform moves via an animation.

---

**Components**

```
platform
  +  rigidbody 
  +  box collider

ball
  +  rigidbody 
  +  sphere collider
```

When the ball comes in contact with the platform, the ball should stop its current velocity and attain the velocity of the platform it is in contact with. However currently, the ball just falls straight through the platform as if there is no colliders attached.

Code of Player:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

public Text winText;
public float speed;
public Text countText;
public GameObject light;

public GameObject player;
private Rigidbody rb;
private int count;
private int a = 0;
private int b = 0;
private int c = 0;

void Start ()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    count = 0;
    SetCountText ();
    winText.text = "";
}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (player.transform.position.y < -15) {
        transform.position = new Vector3(a, b, c);

    }
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    rb.AddForce (movement * speed );

}
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Pick Up"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        count = count + 1;
        SetCountText ();
    }
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Check point"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        light.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        a = 0;
        b = -10;
        c = 96;
    }
}
void SetCountText ()
{
    countText.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();
    if (count >= 8)
    {
        winText.text = "You Win!";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Keep in mind that using Transform components to move physic objects can lead to physic not being applied properly : could be a cause depending on your ball controller ?

Answer (score 3):

You said you are using a custom controller. Please make sure that you are not using `Transform()` to change the ball's position manually and  move your ball as this defies the physics laws in unity. Instead use `Rigidbody.MovePosition()`.
More at [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)

Comment: I added my code of Player, so i should use Rigidbody.MovePosition().

Comment: I believe the problem lies in these lines :

Comment: I believe the problem lies in these lines : 
if (player.transform.position.y < -15) {
        transform.position = new Vector3(a, b, c);

    }

If the new position you set  is through or below the platform, the ball will fall. I don't understand why you manually set it here, but if it's meant to reset the ball's position then make sure that it's positioned above the platform.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you have all those game objects in same Z axis.
- Throw a debug.log() message in your OnCollisionEnter2D() method to see if they are actually colliding.
- Could you also check for the type of Colliders you are using.

More Details about Collision in unity : 
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

Also if it a custom controller make sure that something is not changing the position of ball to go below the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Fast moving objects need the dynamic ContinuousDynamic or Continuous mode to work reliable

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both rigidbodies are kinetic and the colliders are not triggers. Thats what really worked for me.